# Is there some api (or way) for get log when app or service get crashed android?

Tags: android, service, crash, android-service

I am building an app which has a Service, 
this service save the gps coordinates, and check connection with server (yet not validate internet connection only server connection)
this work well,

The App could be closed and the service continue working (checked and working fine)

the UI is updated from service, and this work well, but I yet dont know what moment "it is crashes" I DONT get the typical message "app has stopped" for that I thoungh the services is stop and the UI.

this could work fine for long time, but I (yet) dont know what moment what is get "crashed" because when I enter the UI which must be updated from UI it is not updated (then the service must be started again)

my question is..
Is there some api or way for get the log when service get crashed?

Comment: Removed threads tag since this question doesn't mention threads at all.

Comment: Try using acra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed, Fabric is a great one. Nice and easy to implement and it even has a plugin for Android Studio.

You could also look at Firebase which provides a similar service but you can also quite nicely log your own exceptions too, even if the app doesn't crash.

https://www.fabric.io/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/

Comment: the app is not crashing, but the service is stopped apparently when the app get internet and try send the coordinates

Comment: Fabric really is easy to implement. It might help find your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to go through following options :

https://www.fabric.io (Logs all crashes)

https://github.com/joshdholtz/Sentry-Android (Logs all unhandled exceptions)

Comment: then  the best of those option is fabric?

Comment: yes , Fabric is best. Go with Fabric(Twitter) as it is maintained well & integration is one click in your app.